# SetThreadAffinityMask for unix systems

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, scheduling

I would like to prevent a thread being executed on more than one core, respectively I don't want that when a certain thread is being executed on one core, it should not be scheduled to be executed on another core.

I use the x86 instruction RDTSC to generate timestamps. When this instruction is called from different CPU cores, different timestamp counters might be used and since the different counters are not synchronized through the CPU cores, there might emerge inconsistent results.

On windows there is a function to force this behavior:

```
DWORD_PTR WINAPI SetThreadAffinityMask(
  __in  HANDLE hThread,
  __in  DWORD_PTR dwThreadAffinityMask
);
```

> Sets a processor affinity mask for the specified thread.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Is there something similiar for unix systems?

Comment: You know that `gettimeofday()` will use HPET under Linux, don't you? This is like RDTSC, except it's independent of CPU frequency, reliable, and does not require tampering with affinity masks.

Comment: @Damon The resolution of gettimeofday() is to low for profiling instructions, isn't it?

Comment: The resolution is microseconds, so if you plan to profile just a dozen isolated instructions, yes. But if you profile a _realistic_ piece of code on a realistic dataset (and only that really makes sense tbh) then it is entirely sufficient. Knowing whether a sequence of 10 assembler instructions runs in 30 or 40 cycles doesn't tell you anything valuable. What matters is how the code performs when running over e.g. half a megabyte of _real data_, pipelined in some surrounding code, and with branch predition and cache effects. Those things are 3 orders of magnitude more important.

Comment: (By the way, it's funny that in this case, the precision is better than the resolution, often it's the other way around. But HPET actually offers tens of nanoseconds precision at least on more modern sytems, only `timeval` doesn't hold that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Solaris, you can use CPU binding which can be applied to single threads, single processes, set of processes or all processes in a zone. See [processor_bind](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19082-01/819-2241/processor-bind-2/index.html) and [pbind](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/pbind-1m/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Linux 2.5.8 and higher has [sched_setaffinity()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity). It's often used at the process level, but also works with threads:

> The affinity mask is actually a
>   per-thread attribute that can be
>   adjusted independently for each of the
>   threads in a thread group. The value
>   returned from a call to `gettid`(2) can
>   be passed in the argument `pid`.